PYTHON: How to resolve inhomogenous shape?
I am attempt to save data in a *.npy file, using np.save.
But encounter this error: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (200, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
Concerned codelines are:
dataset = []

#within some loop:
   img = cv2.imread(image_file,1)
   img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
   img = img.astype(np.float32)
   locations = [value1, value2, value3, value4] #(1x4) vector of integer values
   dataset.append(np.array(img), np.array(locations), predicted_class, filename) #predicted_class is an integer and filename is a string\`

Basically, the code iterates through a collections of images and performs some operations on such images that outputs the (1x4) vector. The image and its operated-output are then added to the dataset.
I inspected the dataset, it has the correct number of processed images (len(dataset)) and it has the correct structure:
 [ array([[[#,#,#],...,[#,#,#]]], dtype=float32), array([#,#,#,#]), #, 'filename.jpg']
But when I attempt to save it
np.save('dataset.npy',dataset)

I encounter the error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1b033c5c2e47> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 print(dataset[0])
      3 os.chdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Misc/')
----> 4 np.save('dataset.npy', dataset)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in save(file, arr, allow_pickle, fix_imports)
    543 
    544     with file_ctx as fid:
--> 545         arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
    546         format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
    547                            pickle_kwargs=dict(fix_imports=fix_imports))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (200, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

Any suggestion for how this might be resolved?

The problem here is that there is no way that numpy can form an array that has the same length for value1, value2, etc. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476564/the-requested-array-has-an-inhomogeneous-shape-after-1-dimensions-the-detected

You may find it easier to form 4 separate lists. The first contains all value1, the second contains all value2, etc. If you did that, you could use np.savez() to save all of them to the same file.

arr = np.asanyarray(arr) tries to make a (numeric) array from your list,p.  It canpt because it contains a mix of objects.  dataset=np.array(dataset, dtype=object) before save will get around that.  But you need to allow pickling on loading.  Or just use pickle instead of np.save

Try using a dictionary for your dataset.
dataset = {}

#within some loop:
dataset[filename] = {}
dataset[filename]['img'] = np.array(img)
dataset[filename]['locations'] = np.array(locations)

np.save('dataset.npy',dataset)

d = np.load('dataset.npy', allow_pickle=True).item()


Note that even here it wraps the dict in a numpy array, hence the need to extract it on loading with item().  When saving it pickles the dict.
